# Emotional Speech Generation

Tags: python, text-to-speech

I am using the Tacotron2+Waveglow model by Nividia to generate audiobooks. I want to figure out a way to make the generated audio include more emotions and sound less monotone.

This could be through the text itself or having given it the generated audio to add emotions to it.

Comment: Have you considered trying [Piper](https://github.com/rhasspy/piper). It has decent text-to-speech and their Github page links to a large selection of voice packs (they use an onnx configuration, so you might be able to use the voice data or convert them for use with the nVidia project you're using)